# Decomposition length in the stable homeomorphism conjecture

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, transformation-groups

Stable homeomorphism theorem (due to Brown--Gluck, Kirby, Quinn,...) states that any orientation preserving homeomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is stable, that is, it can be written as a superposition $g_1g_2\dots g_k$ of homeomorphisms where each $g_i$ is identity on some nonempty open subset $U_i\subset\mathbb R^n$.

**The question: Let $\nu(f)$ be the minimal possible number $k$ in the decomposition $g_1g_2\dots g_k$. Once the dimension $n$ is fixed, is $\nu$ unbounded?**

I don't understand the proof but it seems that the decompositions obtained are wildly unbounded.
I can't find a single criterion of a homeomorphism to require at least $k>1$ components $g_i$ to proceed with the construction of 'arbitrary long' homeomorphisms.

Comment: Does the Corollary on page 54 of Brown, Gluck. Stable structures on manifolds answer your question? (That this number equals 1 or 2)

Comment: @MaximPrasolov It does, thank you! If you write this as an answer I will be glad to accept it.